# can the hostname changed via DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, hostname

According to several comments in the web most DHCP clients simply ignore the hostname provided by the DHCP server. Does Ubuntu use the provided hostname?
If not, how can Ubuntu be persuaded to use the provided hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's not talk about how much time I spent finding this answer, but here it is:

switch from isc dhcpclient to dhcpcd5, and it will JUST WORK!

No need to hack around trying to get dhclient-exit-hooks.d to work, no need to hack around getting something to run /etc/init.d/hostname.sh, just run dhcpcd, renew your lease, and there you are.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can do that with /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf's option:

request host-name;

See the example at the end of dhclient.conf(5)

Comment: Ubuntu enables this by default, but it seems no one cares about the hostname returned by the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an empty hostname (which is contained in `/etc/hostname`) works for at least Ubuntu 14.04 (just be sure to renew your DHCP-lease or restart of course).

Then as an optional step - if you care about messages like `unable to resolve host <hostname>` - you would have to change `/etc/hosts` dynamically to point your loopback address to the acquired hostname.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 you could place a script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` containing the following to accomplish that optional step:

```
if [ -n "${new_host_name}" ]; then
  sed -i "/127.0.1.1/c\127.0.1.1 ${new_host_name}" /etc/hosts
fi
```

Then of course make it executable by means of `chmod +x my-custom-script`.